# Vim Overlength highlighting for certain filetypes only

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm using the following in my .vimrc to highlight lines that over 80 characters long:

```
highlight OverLength ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
match OverLength /\%81v.\+/
```

This affects all of my files. Is there a way I can set this to only affect a certain filetype, such as a Javascript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save those lines to a file named `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` on Unix or `~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\javascript.vim` on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Use `au Filetype ... source ...` to source a file containing the commands for the appropriate file types.